# Why my threaded winsock server won't crash?

Tags: winapi, winsock, serversocket, buffer-overflow

I have implemented a c++ winsock (win 32) with intention of crashing using an `strcpy` command.  The socket itself is instantiated inside a thread. However, when I put the `strcpy` inside the `recv` loop, it does not seem to crash.

I know there is nothing wrong with the compiler since writing one with just `strcpy` crashes, I am thinking it is related to `recv` since it initiates a block on the process.

Here is the full code below for the sever, the crash I am trying to implement is in the form of `strcpy(a, "AAAA...");` in regular circumstances it should crash, but here it does not.  I would like to know why.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include<windows.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define DEFAULT_PORT "1133"
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512

struct thread_data
{
   int m_id;
   thread_data(int id) : m_id(id){}
};

char a[10];

DWORD WINAPI ServerThread (LPVOID pParam){
WSADATA wsaData;
struct addrinfo *result =NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;
SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;


do{
  ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

  int iResult;
  iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

  iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL,DEFAULT_PORT,&hints, &result);



  if (iResult != 0 ){
     printf("get addrinfo failed with error %d\n", iResult);
     WSACleanup();
     return 1;
  } //end if 

 ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
 if (ListenSocket ==0){
   printf("socket creation failed  with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
 }
//bind socket
iResult= bind( ListenSocket , result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);


if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR){
  printf("bind failed with  error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
  freeaddrinfo(result);

  closesocket(ListenSocket);
  WSACleanup();
  return 1;

}

printf ("initializing socket\n ");

iResult= listen(ListenSocket,SOMAXCONN);

if (iResult== SOCKET_ERROR){
   printf("listen failed with %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
   closesocket(ListenSocket);
   WSACleanup();
   return 1;
}



SOCKET client ;
sockaddr_in from;
int fromlen=sizeof(from);




char temp[1024];
char temp_to_send[1024];
char temp_to_send_vuln[512];
printf("accepting client request\n");
client=accept(ListenSocket, (struct sockaddr*) &from, &fromlen);
printf("accepted socket\n"); 



iResult =1;
int iSendResult =1;
char c;
//start receiving from client
while(   (iResult = recv(client,temp,1024,0 )) > 0 ){



  c = temp[0];
  temp[iResult] = '\0';
  if(c!=13)
  strcat(temp_to_send,temp);


  //if enter is hit echo sent data to client
  if(c ==13 ){
    printf("sending %s \n",temp_to_send);

    //I WANT TO CRASH THE PGORAM HERE!!          
             strcpy(a,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");  

     strcat(temp_to_send_vuln,temp_to_send);
     strcat(temp_to_send_vuln,"\r\n");
     iSendResult = send(client,temp_to_send,strlen(temp_to_send),0);

    //if user types "exit" the client socket would terminate                   
     if (strcmp(temp_to_send,"exit") ==0){
       printf("exit entered\n");


       closesocket(client);
       WSACleanup();
       break;

     }



     re-initialize variables for next input                            
      temp[0] = '\0';
      temp_to_send[0] = '\0';

    }//end if(ch ==13)


 }//end recv

 printf("termination of socket with error %d and buffer length is ", WSAGetLastError());

 printf("client said %s\n", temp) ;
 if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR){
    printf("receiving failed with error %d",WSAGetLastError());
 }





 if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR){
   printf("seding failed with error %d", WSAGetLastError());
   closesocket(client);
   WSACleanup();
   exit(1);

 }






} while(1);

closesocket(ListenSocket);

WSACleanup();
printf("program ended\n");

return 0;


}

//the main function that calls the thread
int main(void)
{
   //create thread here
   CreateThread(NULL, 0 ,ServerThread, new thread_data(0), 0,0);

   //terminate program when escape character is hit
   while(_getch()!=27);

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Can I get a job at your place?   I am good at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `strcpy()` call is just trashing a and then whatever else happens to be after it in global memory; it's undefined whether it'll crash or not. If you really want to crash out, just call `strcpy( NULL, "whatever" )`.

Comment: If you really want to force a crash, just `throw` your own exception directly, instead of trying to coherce the RTL into throwing one.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I'm actually trying to simulate a buffer overflow....  how is strcpy trashing "a" ?

Comment: It's trashing whatever's after 'a', actually. Your problem is that it's not defined whether that is memory you own. If you want an OS exception you need to write somewhere you're certain not to own, such as NULL.

Comment: ok I get you, so i need to find a way to generate an access memory violation, thanks